# VBA Excel: copy paste named range with hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any smart way to copy paste values from a named range from one sheet to another not including hidden rows?

Comment: What problem are you having with the way you are doing it at the moment?

Comment: That I got the hidden rows when using this type of code: sourceRng.values = targetRng.values. Update: I do not have a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a named range called `MyRange` then you can copy visible cells only to another worksheet using:

```
Sub CopyNamedRange()
    Range("MyRange").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```